# Angularjs textarea data binding issue in Android 4.0.4 browser

Tags: android, angularjs, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, mobile-website

I am working on for creating mobile web application using Angularjs. In one of my page, i used text area for getting some information from user. Also showing users how many characters more remaining, so they aware of maximum limit.

The issue i am getting is, UI is not updating the remaining characters value, during typing inside text area. Furthermore, remaining characters value updates, when user press enter or go to typing next line in text area.

Above issue is not reproducing in PC  web browser, iOS safari browsers and Samsung Galaxy phone browser. Only issue i am getting is for Android Tablet running Android OS version 4.0.4.

Here is sample code:

```
<textarea id="textAreaId" name="textAreaName" class="input-block-level" rows="7" placeholder="Enter your text here." ng-model="oTextArea"></textarea>

<div>length {{oTextArea.length}}</div>
<div>text {{oTextArea}}</div>
```

In above code length and text div did not update value during typing inside text area for Android Tablet running Android OS version 4.0.4.

if anyone know any solution or reason why it is happening for Android Tablet, then please let me know. Thanks in advance.